# Python initialising object in a loop

Tags: python, class, object, for-loop

What is going on here?
I would have thought `b=a()` would create an empty instance of the class.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,l=[]):
        self.l=l

for i in range(2):
    b=a()
    b.l.append(1)
    print b.l
```

results in:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have list as default argument, a new list is created *only once*, when the function is defined, then the *same* list is used in each call. To "solve" this, you can do:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,l=None):
        if l is None:
            self.l = []
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read a nice explanation of what's going on here : http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

```
>>> def function(data=[]):
...     data.append(1)
...     return data
...
>>> function()
[1]
>>> function()
[1, 1]
>>> function()
[1, 1, 1]
```

And the proper way to do it in your case:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        if l is None:
            l = []
        self.l=l

for i in range(2):
    b=a()
    b.l.append(1)
    print b.l
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do **l=[]** in function arguments list - you declare **static list** (list object will be created only once), so each time you append new element to **the same list object**.

You might need something like this to create new list object for each new A object:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        self.l = l or []

for i in range(2):
    b=A()
    b.l.append(1)
    print b.l
```